# Visualise the current state of an application

Tags: info-visualisation, application-state

I'm working on an application where the user can have different states. Depending on the chosen state, the application would have different functionality. The application allows the user to create different objects that contain data that can get filtered or manipulated in any way.

The states would be to have no conflicts between users whilst working in the same application. They can create more objects or manipulate them as desired whilst no other users will see these changes.

The request is to visualise this throughout the UI, but as I haven't seen this much around it's hard to find examples.

I need to visualise it using the name of the state.

Comment: _Many_ non-trivial applications have states or modes that the user can switch between. I think the question is too broad to attract answers beyond a long list of examples. Can you provide any more information about what the application is, what the different states are and who the user is?

Comment: Can you add working ideas to help others visualize what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

[Affinity Designer](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/) does that. You can change the state of the application by switching between vector, pixel and export modes.

They use these toggles:

[image]

The user knows on which mode he is by seeing tools only available on the mode he selected.